# Format wordpress posts to use post title in URL instead of numeric autoincrement?

Tags: wordpress

All my blog post URLs currently look like this: http://www.HeyItsMyBlog.com/?p=368

I want to change the URLs so instead they look like http://www.HeyItsMyBlog.com/2010/11/new-kittens-omg/

This is an easy change in the WordPress admin panel, but there are a bunch of people who have linked to my currently-formatted URLs around the web. How can I make the transition and ensure that it won't break the old links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of Wordpress automagically interprets URLs of the form `?p=777` by redirecting the user to the corresponding pretty URL. You don't need to do anything special beyond enabling pretty URLs in the admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

It works either way (when you set the permalink to your desired one). Test it of course. And oh, this question belongs to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com