# Can't get .htaccess working on Ubuntu Server

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I can't figure out how to get the `.htaccess` file on my new Ubuntu server working. I've tried following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles), but /etc/apache2/sites-available/default is apparently missing. I tried using the `ls` command, and all that comes up is default-ssl.conf.

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10, and I think the latest  version of Apache. Seems to me that the `default.conf` might have been deleted or something, but I'm not sure.

Also, the `.htaccess` has an owner of `www-data`. Maybe just changing the owner would allow me to edit the file?

EDIT: Please note, I'm 100% new to this, so please explain things to me like I'm a 3 year old.

Comment: You will get used to this stuff, just be patient with yourself ;-)

Comment: So is your problem that you can't edit the file?

Comment: Are you trying to edit using FTP or command line? If you are logged in as root you can edit anything. If not maybe try using that user or `sudo`. then you can use vim or nano to edit the file.

Comment: @JonLin, pretty much, yes. I try to edit it, and it just reverts back to whatever it was.

Comment: @PanamaJack Yes, I'm using FTP, and an admin account. Is that different than root?

Comment: Yes the FTP user may not own the file and have permission to change it. If you have root access chown the file to FTP user and group.

Comment: I tried using chown, but it says 'changing owner ship of .htaccess: Operation not permitted'. I'm pretty sure my user has root access, I've been able to do everything else, and as far as I'm aware, this is the only account I've set up.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to use sudo. It worked fine, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to put this in a comment, but this might help.

I've never used Ubuntu but have worked with Apache on Red Hat Enterprise Linux. If you have root access to the machine then the preferable way to add authentication or whatever configurations you want to put in the .htaccess file is to put them in the "httpd.conf" file or main configuration file.

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf  The main configuration file.
/etc/httpd/conf.d/  An auxiliary directory for configuration files that are included in the main configuration file.

cd into the /etc/apache2/ dir and then "ls -ll" and see if you have "conf/" or "conf.d". Instead of adding configurations to the main config file you can have separate ones instead, just depends on how you want to do it. It's easier to start with the main config file.

For example, if you can get to main config file("httpd.conf") at the bottom of it there will be "Section 3" I believe. If you are using vim enter "/Section 3" and it will take you straight to it. You will see an example of a virtual hosts configuration and below that you can add the directories of your web server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@penguin.example.com
 DocumentRoot /www/docs/penguin.example.com
 ServerName penguin.example.com
 ErrorLog logs/penguin.example.com-error_log
 CustomLog logs/penguin.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>



<Directory /var/www>
  Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride AuthConfig
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

If you are using .htaccess files they are hidden so to see them you use "ls -a" when in the directory containing the .htaccess files.

So, back to your question, use "ls -a" to find the .htaccess files. All files with .something are hidden files. You could temporarily change the permissions to 777 just to make things easier so you can edit them and then change them back when you are done. Just make sure you change the permissions back to what they were. To find the permissions use "ls -ll".

```
# chmod 777 .htaccess
```

Comment: Good information, I'll give this a shot, and report back. Essentially all I want to do is enable WordPress to include post names in URLs.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to change http://thewebsite/p?=232 to http://thewebsite/2012/10/31/title-of-posing - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278130/format-wordpress-posts-to-use-post-title-in-url-instead-of-numeric-autoincrement

Comment: Enable pretty URLs in admin panel?

Comment: That requires WordPress to update the .htaccess file, as far as I'm aware. If I enable it, it acts like it doesn't through any errors, but none of the URLs work.